# Does retry() on an Observable created by Observable.defer() trigger a fresh Observable?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactivex

```
private Observable<String> serverResponsesStream() {
    return Observable.defer(() -> Observable.combineLatest(
            ComSocketFactory.createObservable(), // generates new Observable<ComSocket> instance
            getMessageStream(),
            (comSocket, msg) -> {
                try {
                    final String serverResponse = comSocket.transfer(msg);
                    if (serverResponse == null) {
                        throw new IOException("Server response is null.");
                    }
                    return serverResponse;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw OnErrorThrowable.from(e);
                }
            }));
}


// ...

    serverResponsesStream()
            .retry()
            .subscribe(// do something);
```

Did I understand correctly that since I'm subscribing on an Observerable with `defer()` the consequence of using `retry()` will be that my `ComSocketFactory` generates a fresh `Observable<ComSocket>` instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to docs

> Returns an Observable that calls an Observable factory to create an Observable for each new Observer that subscribes.

`Observable.retry()` resubscribes to Observable, so yes - you get fresh Observable from `ComSocketFactory.createObservable()`.